# Unable to get user_birthday from facebook

Tags: facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using [cordova-plugin-facebook4](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4) in my Ionic app. i want user's `name, gender, email, birthday`

```
window.facebookConnectPlugin.login(['public_profile', 'user_birthday', 'email']
,function(response){
    window.facebookConnectPlugin.api(response.authResponse.userID+'/?fields=id, name, gender, email, birthday', ['public_profile', 'user_birthday', 'email'], function(resFromApi){
      console.log(resFromApi);
    }, function(error){
          console.log(error)
    });
},function (error) { console.log(error) });
```

As you can see, i've already included `user_birthday` permission, but i'm getting only `name, gender and email`, and not birthday

```
{
    id: "123456789012345",
    name: "Kanav Kapoor",
    gender: "male",
    email: "sample@email.com"
}
```

The facebook pop also doesn't asks for birthday.

[image: Facebook permission]

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Could you check whether this user actually has a public birthday? If it is private or empty nothing will be returned.

Comment: Does it matters in API as well?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the culprit was Facebook. They didn’t give my app the permission to view user’s birthday. Yesterday, I submitted my App to Facebook for review, and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Some options to use need permission from the facebook team. These options are available on the review page of your facebook application.
You should mark the hits that exceed the public information of the user profile, make a justification for each one, and send a version of your application for facebook team, analysis, check and authorize.

[Login Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSmRS.png)